# How to create New model object by reference of another Model

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have a function in which I take model as parameter to create slug value from that model values and after creating slug i want to check existence of that in same table.

```
public static function slug_it($model = null)
{
  if(!empty($model)) {
    #from model
    $keys = [/*priority => key to find*/
        1 => 'name', 2 => 'item', 4 => 'title', 3 => 'code', 5 => 'company', 6 => 'code_name', 7 => 'country', 8 => 'city', 9 => 'state', 10 => 'username', 11 => 'first_name', 12 => 'last_name',];
    /* suppose i have slug */
    $slug = 'item_erp5511'; 

    /*slug or sku*/
  } else {

  }
}
```

Suppose Model is of item table and I want to find slug in "slug" col of that table but **i only have Model Object of that table**.

Comment: Please try and adding more details in the post.

Comment: problem is like i have i have 2-3 table and all  of them have slug so i want to create one method in which i can create slug from model values then check in same table and if its unique that i insert otherwise new slug and so on ... so i want one generic method which i can use with any model.

Answer (score 3):

You can try something like the following, presumption, `$model = Item::class` instance and you want to find something from the `slugs` table.

```
// $model = Item::find(1);
$model->getQuery()->from('slugs')->where('slug', $slug)->get();
```

Alternatively if `slug_it` is inside a model you can try:

```
self::getQuery()->from('slugs')->....->get();
```

**Update after your latest comment**

Inside the method to do a check you can do:

```
if (self::where('slug', $slug)->exists()) {
    // Do what you need
}
```

Comment: thanks but actually i want one generic method that i can use with any model so i can reuse this method for slugs as a discussed in my comment above.